# One image moves when I center the other

Tags: html, css

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydBMp.jpg)

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to make a simple page consisting of a title, a map picture, a picture of a pin that will overlay the map picture on a certain spot (I'm doing it this way instead of just making a jpeg with the pin because it'll be moving around later), and some info text under it. For some reason, when I center the map image, the pin image starts moving around horizontally when I resize the window. Id really appreciate some help with this!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>CampusSpots York University</title>  
</head> 

<body>

<h1 style= "font-size:9; text-align:center"> York University </h1>    

<img src="map.jpg" alt="map" style="width: 650px; height: 450px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto"/>

<img src="Pin.png" alt="pin" style="position: fixed; width: 20px; height: 35px; top: 200px;left: 300px;"/>

<p style= "position: relative; bottom: auto; text-align: center"><strong>Important Numbers</strong><br><strong>York Security (General):</strong>416-650-8000<br><strong>York Security (Urgent): </strong>416-736-5333<br><strong>York goSAFE: </strong>416-736-5454<br><strong>Emergency:</strong> 911<br><strong>For General Inquiries:</strong> 416-736-2100<br></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have tones of errors in your HTML. You probably should fix them first and then come back with valid HTML code. There are many tools that can highlight the errors for you and suggest fixes.

Comment: You're right racial, I'll do that now and edit. And Suraj, I need this specific map because it has details on it that google maps does not.

Comment: OK, good! Now about your question, The first image is centered, so it is normal that it moves when your resize the window, because the center has moved. And the second image is fixed to 500px from the left, so it will never move when resizing the window. This is contrary to what you said, it is the first image that moves, not the second. Now if that's not what you want, you'll have to tell us what you want. Do you want both images to stay centered on top of each other, so they move together? Then we'll show you how to center the second one. Do you want both fixed? Then fix the first one.

Comment: Hey Racil, so I've reposted the edited HTML, basically, I want the "pin" picture (the second one) to stay on top of a specific building on the map (first picture), and to always appear on that spot on the map no matter how I resize the window or if its opened on a phone or anywhere else. I can't seem to get the pictures to stay fixed while still centering the map picture. as a matter of fact, the map picture does not stay centered, even with the "margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" command. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: can you provide like a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I added the image, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've change how you're centering the contents, so I will answer according to your new code. A couple of things:

- You're trying to center the first image by defining auto margins. That only works on block elements, but the `img` element is an inline element, so you have to make it block `display: block`. By the way, you can simply make all margins auto `margin: auto` since you don't really specify top and bottom margins, but your way is fine so I left it as is.
- Your second image must be `position: absolute` in order for it to overlap the first image. Now, if you want to center it, then use `left: 50%` and then give it a negative left margin equals to half of its width `margin-left: -10px`. This will make it exactly centered like the first image and they both will move together when resizing the window. If the second image should not be exactly in the center and it needs to be off the center to overlap some spot of the first image, then change the value of the left margin until you get the result you want (or you can do it scientifically by measuring how much off-center the spot on the first image is, then subtract half of the width of the second image and change the result to negative then assign that value to the left margin).

Here is a working example:

```html
<h1 style= "font-size: 9; text-align: center;"> York University </h1>

<img src="map.jpg" alt="map" style="width: 650px; height: 450px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;"/>

<img src="Pin.png" alt="pin" style="position: absolute; width: 20px; height: 35px; top: 200px; left: 50%; margin-left: -10px;"/>

<p style= "position: relative; bottom: auto; text-align: center"><strong>Important Numbers</strong><br><strong>York Security (General):</strong>416-650-8000<br><strong>York Security (Urgent): </strong>416-736-5333<br><strong>York goSAFE: </strong>416-736-5454<br><strong>Emergency:</strong> 911<br><strong>For General Inquiries:</strong> 416-736-2100<br></p>
```

Comment: Racil thank you so much, I really appreciate that, it worked perfectly! Best wishes to you!